# Existence of small full abelian subcategory

Tags: category-theory

I got confused with the following exercise. I do not understand why can not we always take C, 0, kernel and cokernel for any element of $C$ as objects of $B$ (or it is true?). There is also a hint that I should use axioms of union and replacement, but I have no idea how should proof look like.

Let A be an abelian category, and $C\subset Ob(A)$ a subset of objects. Show that there exists a small full abelian subcategory $B$ of $A$, such that $C\subseteq Ob(B)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I fixed it.